# regex only matches a certain word

Tags: regex

I want to match a exact word "hello"

following cases should find the match.

```
hello world
hello, 
hello
hello。
```

following cases should not find the match

```
helloy
hello我
```

I tried

```
\bhello\b
```

, it seems to work except the last one. If english words mix with non-english words, how to not match hello我。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\bhello\b
```

will work provided you use `u` or `unicode` flag.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/12